# Sqlalchemy Define Multiple One-to-One Relationships between same Schemas (and a backref)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I cannot seem to get around a `AmbigiousForeignKeyError` here. Here is currently what I'm dealing with

```
class Node(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'nodes'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=true)

    prev_change = relationship("NodeChange", back_populates="new_node", uselist=False)
    next_change = relationship("NodeChange", back_populates="old_node", uselist=False)

Class NodeChange(Base):

    __tablename__ = "node_changes"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=true)
    date = Column(Date)

    old_node_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('nodes.id'))
    old_node = relationship("Node", foreign_keys=[old_node_id])

    new_node_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('nodes.id'))
    new_node = relationship("Node", foreign_keys=[new_node_id])
```

The idea behind this is to traverse node objects via node change objects that store time related information (is the change viable or not etc.)

Both relationships here are one-to-one. I have gotten this working while excluding the `prev_change` and `next_change` backrefs, but cannot get the 2 way relationship working  without encountering a `AmbigiousForeignKeyError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to fix this looks to be:

1. remove the `prev_change` and `next_change` relationships from `Node`
2. add them as `backref` to the `old_node` and `new_node`

This is how new relationships look like:

```
old_node = relationship(
    "Node", foreign_keys=[old_node_id],
    backref=backref('prev_change', uselist=False),
)

new_node = relationship(
    "Node", foreign_keys=[new_node_id],
    backref=backref('next_change', uselist=False),
)
```